# Any chance to add custom code or an application to "Open with" option at Files?

Tags: pantheon-files

Any chance that I can open a file with custom codes or a custom made application or a Wine software at Files? I can do that with Dolphin or Nemo, but I don't like Nemo that much and Dolphin is too heavy and slow for me. I love Files except this particular thing. I searched at here and Google but couldn't find a solution and I don't mean it like this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92494/how-to-add-open-folder-as-root-in-elementary-os-file-manager-context-menu

At least a way to open files with Wine applications.

Comment: What's wrong with the method in the posted link? Contract files can easily do what you ask (`open a file with custom codes or a custom made application or a Wine software`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this is adding the specific MIME type to the *.desktop* file you use to launch a application.

I created this file `~/.local/share/applications/vscode.desktop` to launch VSCode from Slingshot. If I want it to open a .vala file from Files, I have to add "MimeType=text/vala" to the "vscode.desktop" and it will appear in the "Open with..." menu.

There's a nice GUI for managing .desktop files called MenuLibre. You can install it from Software Center or `sudo apt-get install menulibre`

Example of a .desktop file: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/apa.html

Comment: I liked Menu Libre and seems like your way is a okay workaround. I hope in the future they add custom code etc. option to pantheon-file manager.