# Chrome apps as default applications

Tags: applications, google-chrome

Can you make a chrome application default to open files in pantheon?

I would like to set `.txt` files to open a application called "text" which is a chrome application.

Comment: There's a way to call a arbitrary application on the "Open with" menu. Take a look in this answer: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2109/2461

BUT I don't know if you can pass a file (local path) to a chrome application as it is, after all, a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as in the example below (I used Google Docs as I do not have the other app but it should work exactly in the same way).

1. Install the chrome app in question in the application menu (right-click and *Create shortcuts…* in Chrome Apps tab). For me it created the file `~/.local/share/applications/chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default.desktop`, find the `.desktop` that corresponds to your Chrome App.
2. Append `%F` with a text editor in the `Exec=` line (see below):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Name=Google Docs
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake %F
   Icon=chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default
   StartupWMClass=crx_aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake
   ```
3. Right-click on the file you want to open in *Files*, select *Open with*, look for you application and assign it as default (or leave it as an option in the context menu, as wanted).